# Asking about intuitive ways to do things?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on something where I can draw and edit polygons on a map. I'm not sure what the best technique for removing vertices is. Programmatically I have no issues, I know exactly what I need to do to remove a vertex, I'm just not sure what the best user interaction to use for the user to specify which vertex.

What is the best way to ask an SO question when the programming task is easy, but user experience is the challenge? Is there a better StackExchange site for user experience and interface questions like this?

Comment: There is a [User Experience Stack Exchange site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/7202/)

Comment: @Jim that seems like a valid answer to me

Comment: The programming forum has many people that deal with vertices and GUI elements, and so does the gaming forum,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For User Experience questions, there is a [User Experience Stack Exchange site](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

From their FAQ:

> User Experience - Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.